# Attempting to play video on iOS 7 shows play button with line through

Tags: iphone, ios, video

When I try to watch video in my browser I get a play button with a line through it and it doesn't work. I have tried Safari, Chrome, and Mercury. They all give me the play button with a line through it. When I use my old iPhone with iOS 6 I have no issues. This seems to be an iOS 7 issue.

[image]

Comment: Video from what website?

Comment: This means the video is in the wrong format to be played on the device. Why it works in iOS 6 but not iOS 7 I'm not sure — I didn't think anything changed.

Comment: Does this happen with every video you try?

Comment: @zigg The mobile version of youtube and dailymotion.

Comment: @dwightk its random. I don't know why its random.

Comment: @cokedude Blows my mind then, both of those sites work perfectly on my 4S with 7.1 (and did with 7). I prefer the sites over the apps, actually.

Comment: @zigg my old phone is 4S. Any ideas of what to try?

Comment: happening to me too. Will play fine when connected to wifi but not when using cellular data

Comment: Users can disable mobile streaming of videos on a per-video basis on YouTube -- are you sure you're not just hitting videos that don't support mobile streaming?

Comment: I have the same problem but only on the website genvideos

Answer (score 1):

Well, on an adult website I've been on, i just refreshed the page or went back a page, went back to the same video and it played again. It only gives me that when I turn my phone off and its on the video player. Tried the same thing with my old 4g IPod. Just go back a page and reclick the video., Only if we're on teh same website....

Comment: That's likely because the video URL had an expired key in it and navigating back generated a new key.

Comment: I assume you're talking about the iPod _touch_ 4G?

Answer (score 0):

Try closing ALL other apps, cold start your iPhone, re-open Safari and try again. Several people on other forums have had memory issues with exactly the same consequences. It's definitely NOT an ios version problem.

Comment: Just tested and, awful though it might sound, this is actually right.  I'm going to try sending low resolution video to iPhone to try to avoid crashing the browser.